# How can I Observe a var in a Class?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Here is my code for a simple class, **My goal is** that `observeValueOfModel()` function **automatically** put changes of valueOfModel **under control** and print the correct message out!
I can manually use this func for getting the Answer, but the goal is this class be able understand and react to value change of valueOfModel. Thanks for help

```
class Model: ObservableObject {
            
    var valueOfModel: Bool = Bool()
            
    private func observeValueOfModel() { 
        if valueOfModel { 
            print("valueOfModel is True!") 
        } 
        else { 
            print("valueOfModel is False!") 
        } 
    }  
}
```

Comment: Check out [`CurrentValueSubject`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/currentvaluesubject)

Comment: thanks, any sample code plz?

Comment: Spend the time, read the documentation, and learn something. I would start with: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/722/

Comment: I never could be able to use apple documents I do not understand them

Comment: @Omid, can you show how you plan to use this function? I'm not following your goal here. What does "put changes of valueOfModel under control" mean?

Comment: you mean you did not understand my english or my goal?

Comment: @Omid, your goal as articulated in the question. It might help if you showed more of what you're trying to actually achieve? Is it just to print something whenever the property changes? Then you can use `didSet`

Comment: @NewDev, my Goal is observing a var, sorry for my english and explaining.

Comment: @Omid, look into [didSet](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html#ID262)

Comment: @NewDev, let me give you more info about what I trying to learn, u know SwiftUI! In SwiftUI we have .onChange(), I want to clone something like that

Comment: @Omid That's probably a bigger issue than everything else. You're going to have a *very* rough time programming in the Apple ecosystem if you can't read Apple documentation (which is *very* often the only source of info on their technologies.)

Comment: I understand! I am just beginner, maybe I could use them in future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `didSet` fits in this case

```
class Model: ObservableObject {
            
    var valueOfModel: Bool = Bool() {
       didSet {
         observeValueOfModel()
       }
    }
            
    // ... other code
```

Answer (score 0):

Combine will help you. Define your var as `@Published` to be able to subscribe to it

```swift
@Published var valueOfModel: Bool = true
```

You can subscribe to changes in the `init` or `viewDidLoad` for example. We store the subscription in the `cancelable`. Put it in the VC or as class property to keep the subscription alive.

```swift
let cancelable: AnyCancellable?
```

```swift
cancelable = valueOfModel.sink { [weak self] value
    // this will get called as soon as valueOfModel gets updated
    // do smth with value here
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help, didSet was better and easy for me in this case.